# Why is the app_id on my Ionic.io dashboard different than the one on io-config.json?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-cloud, ionic.io

On my Ionic.io dashboard, the app_id for my app is listed under the title as ID:a44fb59e but on my app folder, if I check the app_id in the .io-config.json file, my app_id is actually dee3748e.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: are you working alone or in a team?

Comment: Alone. However I originally created my app via Ionic CLI (not using ionic io init) and then added the app on the dashboard later (we started using Ionic.io until later). So the Dashboard may have assigned it it's own app_id and I simply have to re-synch on my json file. The strange thing is that push notifications still worked on android regardless of this difference.